# Is $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{n}$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For n>1, $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{n}$, where $f(a) = [a]_{n}$ ($[a]_n$ is the denotation for $a$ mod $n$), is this a homomorphism?  I think it is not because $f(a+b) = [a+b]_n \neq [a]_n + [b]_n$.  Am I correct?

Comment: Can you please show me how this is a homomorphism?

Comment: Why do you think that $[a+b]_n\not=[a_n]+[b_n]$?

Comment: because $[3+4]_7 = 1 \neq [3]_7 + [4]_7 = 7$, right?

Comment: I mean $[3+4]_7 = 0$

Comment: Also, to prove that a mapping in homomorphic would I just have to show that $f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a=a_1n+r_1,~b=a_2n+r_2$. Then according to your definition $f(a+b)=(r_1+r_2)\mod n$. 
Also $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and for $f$ to be a homomorphism it needs to satisfy $f(a+b)=f(a)+_nf(b)$ where $+_n$ is the sum operation of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. But $f(a)+_nf(b)$ is $(r_1+r_2)\mod n$. Hence $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: So are you saying that $f(a + b) = [a+b]_n = [f(a) + f(b)]_n = [[a]_n+[b]_n]_n$ because the sum operation for $\mathbb Z_n$ is mod $n$?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.